# Java app for 3rd party server

Tags: java, web-services, xml-parsing, applet

Im newbie in java. 
I want make a web application (like a remote controller) for 3rd party server(via xml api).

I think to make a java applet for user gui and a service for parcing xml to (and from) 3rd party server. Whole app will run on separate server with apache.

Is it correct way in general or i need change my concept? 
And I need advice how to make communication between web user gui (applet) and service, that parcing xml, on same host? Through or make it in one application with different threads?

Comment: applet is no longer supported by most web browsers...fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applet?  So 1998.

Web UIs in browser speak HTTP to web services now.  Applets are NOT the way to go.

IF you deploy on a Java EE app server or, better yet, Spring Boot, all that threading stuff will be taken care of for you.

It's not for newbies.  By all means attempt if you want to learn; get some help if this is real.